# Sql update using case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update a column in sql server table which is used to generate ID's:
Table structue is something like this

Name varchar(50), LastID long

In last ID we keep Last ID we have generated for something say StudentID. So data will look like this

```
Name :Student, LastID : 50001
```

This last ID is incremeting by 1 to generate a unique Id for (primary key).

Now there is a situation that where we have to reset this LastID to 0 when it reacheachs to Max (say 100000). So I am using

```
Update Sequence 
set    LastID = Case when LastID + @range >= @max then 0 else LastID end 
where  Name ='StudentID'
```

Range is parameter we pass to our store procedure generaly it's 100 in my case. So before seting the LastID I check whether it's exceiding Max for student ID i.e. 1,00,000.

What bothers me in above update query I am again updating LastID to it's current value if it's not excedding the range. Looking for a better alternative. What I don't want to do is:

Using select and keeping LastID in a variable or something like this.

I just want to do in a single update if it's possible.

It's a sql server 2008 databse so I can't use inbuilt sequence feature of sql server 2012.

If more inforamtion is required please let me know.

Comment: There just isn't enough detail to understand this. But [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: It looks like you're missing `then 0` before the `else` in your Case.

Comment: update by adding then.

Comment: Skip the case expression. Move the condition the the WHERE clause instead.

Comment: What @jarlh said. If you don't want to update when the condition isn't true, you can exclude those rows in the `WHERE`. `Update Sequence 
set    LastID = 0 
where  Name ='StudentID' AND LastID + @range >= @max`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to go with your sql code what you could try is

```
Update Sequence 
set    LastID = Case when LastID + @range >= @max then 0 else LastID end 
FROM Sequence
where  Name ='StudentID'
```

More on how to use this syntax is described here [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Moreover I'd not suggest using different approach in your case since you dont want to update value when LastID doesn't meet the criteria so as cf_en suggested filter those values in where clause and then only update the rest of the values

```
Update Sequence 
set    LastID = 0
FROM Sequence
where  Name ='StudentID' and LastID + @range >= @max
```

This query will be much faster since it won't update all rows in db with same value